# dump reader can't find symbol files

Tags: windbg, dump, crash-dumps

I'm trying to learn about reading dump files, so I made my small APP crush, and created a dump for that process from task manager.

I tried to open the .dmp file, both from VS10 and windbg.exe, and got an error that the symbol files are missing. I specified the path of the symbol files as the directory where the .pdb files are located :
..\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CachedQueryTester\CachedQueryTester\bin\Debug

but I still get the same error, both on VS10 and windbg.exe,
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also need symbols from Microsoft , try to enter

```
0:000> .symfix
```

in windbg

Answer (score 0):

From your configuration, you should not have to specify any debug symbol path, because the path of your symbols are stored in the executable. To be sure, you can open a Visual Studio Command prompt and type

> dumpbin CachedQueryTester.exe /HEADERS

In the output, you should have a 'Debug Directories' entry containing the full path of the pdb.

If this is not the case, check you have specified to generate a PDB file (Configuration Properties / Linker / Debugging / Generate debug info);

You can also try to ask WinDbg for the location it looks for. In order to do this, open your dump file from within WinDbg, type '!symnoisy' and reload the symbols (.reload /u then .reload and kb). It will tell you the locations it looks for.